# Typescript Build errors with Angular2 and VS2013 lib.es6.d.ts

Tags: .net, angular

I am working on a new project with `Angular2`.  I am trying to integrate into an existing legacy .NET Web Forms application.
I had things working and building up until upgrading my VS2015 to update 2.  Since then, I am getting build errors associated to a reference to lib.es6.d.ts in my main.ts file.

The errors are like this this for example:

> Build: ";" expected. ...\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts
>       Build: "," expected. ...\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts
>       Build: Type expected. ...\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts

Note, I get these new errors in VS2013 which I have not made any updates recently.
I have tried changing configuration of the typescript settings in the project but cannot get it building again.  Please suggest what may resolve my issues.

Comment: Did you add typings for ES6 shims? those things are essential

Comment: Yes, here is my file:
    {
      "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
        "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
        "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Check '\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts' for red line errors/syntax errors, it should show you the area it's complaining about when it says ' "," expected' and '";" expected'. As for 'Type expected', it looks like some property, method, class, etc may be missing an important type (string, number, array, or a class).

This is an example of a typing I found in my lib.es6.d.ts: `declare function parseFloat(string: string): number;`. If you can locate the red lines/areas producing those 'expected' errors, I would be willing to compare your code with mine in \node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts.

Comment: This is not a file I created so I do not expect syntax errors.  What I have found is that it appears to be a configuration issue.  I have not yet determined where.